# How to get one random data everyday from a table inside a sqlite database?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am working on Quotes Project in iOS. I would like to implement concept of **Quotes of the Day** so I need to select only one data from a table on date basis. How it's possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what part of this is difficult for you?  Is it a problem to get a random value or to read the database or...?